# Silent parameter to activate Office 2013 for images FirstLogonCommand

Tags: imaging

What parameter can I use so that pop-up window stating windows activated successfully doesn't show and make me hit ok after I log in? I put the below command line script in `OOBE > FirstLogonCommand > SynchronousCommand` so it is working but a window pops up.

```
-CommandLine: C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /ato
```

[image: Message Pop-Up I need to bypass without having to click ok]

Answer (score 0):

Update: My solution was to add FirstLogonCommand in my unattend.xml file and add 3 SynchronousCommands under that.

1 to activate windows = C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /ato

2 to ReArm Office = C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\OfficeReArm.cmd

3 to Activate Office 2013 = C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\OfficeActivation.cmd